# Check if full path given

Tags: c#, .net, validation, path

Is there a method to check if given path is full path? Right now im doing this:

```
if (template.Contains(":\\")) //full path already given
{
}
else //calculate the path from local assembly
{
}
```

But there must be more elegant way for checking this?

Answer (score 162, accepted):

Try using `System.IO.Path.IsPathRooted`? It also returns `true` for absolute paths.

```
System.IO.Path.IsPathRooted(@"c:\foo"); // true
System.IO.Path.IsPathRooted(@"\foo"); // true
System.IO.Path.IsPathRooted("foo"); // false

System.IO.Path.IsPathRooted(@"c:1\foo"); // surprisingly also true
System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(@"c:1\foo");// returns "[current working directory]\1\foo"
```

Comment: How come second example be absolute path?

Comment: The second path is not absolute, however it is rooted. The leading slash indicates the root of the system.

Comment: @SmirkinGherkin so what is the difference between a rooted and absolute path?

Comment: As per the [documentation](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/path.cs,807960f08fca497d) 'Tests if the given path contains a root. A path is considered rooted if it starts with a backslash ("\") or a drive letter and a colon (":").' So doesn't explain the difference, but the terminology.

Comment: System.IO.Path.IsPathRooted(@"\\"); // true

Comment: See my answer (http://stackoverflow.com/a/35046453/704808) for an alternative that ensures a full path while retaining the advantages of `IsPathRooted`: avoiding accessing the file system or throwing exceptions for invalid input.

Comment: what das the "1" mean in the last two paths?

Comment: @daniel, IIRC it was included to show that the path didn't need to be a valid path to be used with `IsPathRooted`, it certainly wasn't anything significant. The `GetFullPath` line was included so that the path being evaluated could be observed

Answer (score 44):

```
Path.IsPathRooted(path)
&& !Path.GetPathRoot(path).Equals(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar.ToString(), StringComparison.Ordinal)
```

The above condition:

- does not require file system permissions
- returns `false` in most cases where the format of `path` is invalid (rather than throwing an exception)
- returns `true` only if `path` includes the volume

In scenarios like the one the OP posed, it may therefore be more suitable than the conditions in the earlier answers. Unlike the above condition:

- `path == System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(path)` throws exceptions rather than returning `false` in these scenarios:

  - *The caller does not have the required permissions*
  - *The system could not retrieve the absolute path*
  - *path contains a colon (":") that is not part of a volume identifier*
  - *The specified path, file name, or both exceed the system-defined maximum length*
- `System.IO.Path.IsPathRooted(path)` returns `true` if `path` begins with a single directory separator.

Finally, here is a method that wraps the above condition and also forecloses the remaining possible exceptions:

```
public static bool IsFullPath(string path) {
    return !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(path)
        && path.IndexOfAny(System.IO.Path.GetInvalidPathChars().ToArray()) == -1
        && Path.IsPathRooted(path)
        && !Path.GetPathRoot(path).Equals(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar.ToString(), StringComparison.Ordinal);
}
```

EDIT: EM0 made a good comment and [alternative answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47569899) addressing the curious case of paths like `C:` and `C:dir`. To help decide how you may want to handle such paths, you may want to take deep dive to MSDN --> *Windows desktop applications* --> *Develop* --> *Desktop technologies* --> *Data Access and Storage* --> *Local File Systems* --> *File Management* --> *About File Management* --> *Creating, Deleting, and Maintaining Files* --> *Naming Files, Paths, and Namespaces* --> [Fully Qualified vs. Relative Paths](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx#fully_qualified_vs._relative_paths)

> For Windows API functions that manipulate files, file names can often
>   be relative to the current directory, while some APIs require a fully
>   qualified path. A file name is relative to the current directory if it
>   does not begin with one of the following:
>
> - A UNC name of any format, which always start with two backslash characters ("\"). For more information, see the next section.
> - A disk designator with a backslash, for example "C:\" or "d:\".
> - A single backslash, for example, "\directory" or "\file.txt". This is also referred to as an absolute path.
>
> If a file name begins with only a disk designator but not the
>   backslash after the colon, it is interpreted as a relative path to the
>   current directory on the drive with the specified letter. Note that
>   the current directory may or may not be the root directory depending
>   on what it was set to during the most recent "change directory"
>   operation on that disk. Examples of this format are as follows:
>
> - "C:tmp.txt" refers to a file named "tmp.txt" in the current directory on drive C.
> - "C:tempdir\tmp.txt" refers to a file in a subdirectory to the current directory on drive C.
>
> [...]

Comment: I like that this doesn't throw for invalid paths, but it returns true for paths like "C:" and "C:dir", which are resolved by GetFullPath using the current directory (so they're not absolute). Posted an answer that returns false for these.

Comment: @EM0 - Thanks! You just taught me something. :)

Answer (score 21):

#### On .NET Core 2.1+ and .NET

You can use [`Path.IsPathFullyQualified`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.ispathfullyqualified) ([source](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/217599679c1679db41bfbf28a9969705e4761fa6/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/IO/Path.cs#L280)).

#### On .NET Framework

You can implement the definition of [*fully qualified* (MS Docs)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file#fully-qualified-vs-relative-paths). For example (on Windows):

```cs
public static bool IsPathFullyQualified(string path)
{
    var root = Path.GetPathRoot(path);
    return root.StartsWith(@"\\") || root.EndsWith(@"\") && root != @"\";
}
```

Note the guard against being rooted only by directory and not also by drive. See [`Path.IsPathFullyQualified` Remarks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.ispathfullyqualified#remarks) for more explanation.

Comment: Path.IsPathFullyQualified is good, handles tricky cases like C:

Comment: For .Net Framework, one might want to add a check ```if (string.IsNullOrWhitespace(path)) return false;```, as GetPathRoot throws an exception in such cases.

Answer (score 18):

Building on **weir**'s answer: this does not throw for invalid paths, but also returns `false` for paths like "C:", "C:dirname" and "\path".

```
public static bool IsFullPath(string path)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(path) || path.IndexOfAny(Path.GetInvalidPathChars()) != -1 || !Path.IsPathRooted(path))
        return false;
    
    string pathRoot = Path.GetPathRoot(path);
    if (pathRoot.Length <= 2 && pathRoot != "/") // Accepts X:\ and \\UNC\PATH, rejects empty string, \ and X:, but accepts / to support Linux
        return false;

    if (pathRoot[0] != '\\' || pathRoot[1] != '\\')
        return true; // Rooted and not a UNC path

    return pathRoot.Trim('\\').IndexOf('\\') != -1; // A UNC server name without a share name (e.g "\\NAME" or "\\NAME\") is invalid
}
```

Note that this returns different results on Windows and Linux, e.g. "/path" is absolute on Linux, but not on Windows.

Unit test:

```
[Test]
public void IsFullPath()
{
    bool isWindows = Environment.OSVersion.Platform.ToString().StartsWith("Win"); // .NET Framework
    // bool isWindows = System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(OSPlatform.Windows); // .NET Core

    // These are full paths on Windows, but not on Linux
    TryIsFullPath(@"C:\dir\file.ext", isWindows);
    TryIsFullPath(@"C:\dir\", isWindows);
    TryIsFullPath(@"C:\dir", isWindows);
    TryIsFullPath(@"C:\", isWindows);
    TryIsFullPath(@"\\unc\share\dir\file.ext", isWindows);
    TryIsFullPath(@"\\unc\share", isWindows);

    // These are full paths on Linux, but not on Windows
    TryIsFullPath(@"/some/file", !isWindows);
    TryIsFullPath(@"/dir", !isWindows);
    TryIsFullPath(@"/", !isWindows);

    // Not full paths on either Windows or Linux
    TryIsFullPath(@"file.ext", false);
    TryIsFullPath(@"dir\file.ext", false);
    TryIsFullPath(@"\dir\file.ext", false);
    TryIsFullPath(@"C:", false);
    TryIsFullPath(@"C:dir\file.ext", false);
    TryIsFullPath(@"\dir", false); // An "absolute", but not "full" path

    // Invalid on both Windows and Linux
    TryIsFullPath(null, false, false);
    TryIsFullPath("", false, false);
    TryIsFullPath("   ", false, false); // technically, a valid filename on Linux

    // Invalid on Windows, valid (but not full paths) on Linux
    TryIsFullPath(@"C:\inval|d", false, !isWindows);
    TryIsFullPath(@"\\is_this_a_dir_or_a_hostname", false, !isWindows);
    TryIsFullPath(@"\\is_this_a_dir_or_a_hostname\", false, !isWindows);
    TryIsFullPath(@"\\is_this_a_dir_or_a_hostname\\", false, !isWindows);
}

private static void TryIsFullPath(string path, bool expectedIsFull, bool expectedIsValid = true)
{
    Assert.AreEqual(expectedIsFull, PathUtils.IsFullPath(path), "IsFullPath('" + path + "')");

    if (expectedIsFull)
    {
        Assert.AreEqual(path, Path.GetFullPath(path));
    }
    else if (expectedIsValid)
    {
        Assert.AreNotEqual(path, Path.GetFullPath(path));
    }
    else
    {
        Assert.That(() => Path.GetFullPath(path), Throws.Exception);
    }
}
```

Comment: Good stuff. I did notice that https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx#fully_qualified_vs._relative_paths states that on Windows a path is *not* relative if it begins with *'A single backslash, for example, "\directory" or "\file.txt". This is also referred to as an absolute path.'*

Comment: Good point! Looks like my terminology was off. When I said "absolute path" I was really thinking of what MS calls a "full path". I've changed the name and added a test case for this.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, it helped me a lot. However, note that for a UNC path such as \\server\, the method returns true, but this will throw an exception if you then call Directory.Exists(path) (System.ArgumentException: 'The UNC path should be of the form \\server\share.')

Comment: Nice to see people still using this and finding new edge cases @Carl Updated the code and test for that!

Comment: On Linux, almost anything is allowed as filename character, including the pipe and whitespace-only. This means, that @"C:\inval|d" is allowed, as well as @"\\is_this_a_dir_or_a_hostname".
Even a filename consisting of spaces only (such as "   ") is a valid filename (or directory name). However, for some reason .NET throws exceptions when passing such a string to Path.GetFullPath("   "), or for example File.WriteAllBytes("   ", ...), which is possibly a bug.

Answer (score 14):

Try

```
System.IO.Path.IsPathRooted(template)
```

Works for UNC paths as well as local ones.

E.g.

```
Path.IsPathRooted(@"\\MyServer\MyShare\MyDirectory")  // returns true
Path.IsPathRooted(@"C:\\MyDirectory")  // returns true
```

Comment: This will consider "\\myfolder" as rooted.

Answer (score 13):

Old question, but one more applicable answer.  If you need to ensure the volume is included in a local path, you can use System.IO.Path.GetFullPath() like this:

```
if (template == System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(template))
{
    ; //template is full path including volume or full UNC path
}
else
{
    if (useCurrentPathAndVolume)
        template = System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(template);
    else
        template = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location
}
```

Comment: This was what I needed, and seems closer to the original question since IsPathRooted' returns true for relative paths (not necessarily absolute paths)

Comment: `GetFullPath` accesses the file system and can throw a number of possible exceptions. See my answer (http://stackoverflow.com/a/35046453/704808) for an alternative that still ensures a full path.

Answer (score 11):

As of .NET Core 2.1/NET Standard 2.1, you can call the following method:

```
Path.IsPathFullyQualified(@"c:\foo")
```

MSDN doc: [Path.IsPathFullyQualified Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.ispathfullyqualified)

The useful cite from MSDN doc follows:

> This method handles paths that use the alternate directory separator.
> It's a frequent mistake to assume that rooted paths
> ([IsPathRooted(String)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.ispathrooted?view=netcore-3.0#System_IO_Path_IsPathRooted_System_String_)) aren't relative. For example, "C:a" is drive
> relative, that is, it's resolved against the current directory for C:
> (rooted, but relative). "C:\a" is rooted and not relative, that is,
> the current directory isn't used to modify the path.

Answer (score 6):

This is the solution I use

```
public static bool IsFullPath(string path)
{
    try
    {
        return Path.GetFullPath(path) == path;
    }
    catch
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

It works the following way:

```
IsFullPath(@"c:\foo"); // true
IsFullPath(@"C:\foo"); // true
IsFullPath(@"c:\foo\"); // true
IsFullPath(@"c:/foo"); // false
IsFullPath(@"\foo"); // false
IsFullPath(@"foo"); // false
IsFullPath(@"c:1\foo\"); // false
```

Comment: Very interesting! It's fragile, for instance, has to match slash types, but this has promise.

Comment: It returns wrong results for the following paths: `C:\foo\..\foo` or `C:\foo\.\.\.`

Answer (score -1):

I'm not really sure what you mean by *full path* (though assuming from the example you mean non-relative from the root onwards), well, you can use the [Path](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.aspx) class to aid you in working with physical filesystem paths, which should cover you for most eventualities.