# Binary serialization with dynamically loaded .Net assembly

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, .net-assembly

I serialized an instance of my class into a file (with `BinaryFormatter`)

After, in another project, I wanted to deserialize this file, but it did not  work because my new project does not have the description of my old class. The `.Deserialize()` gets an exception

```
Unable to find assembly '*MyAssembly, Version=1.9.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.*".
```

But I have the .DLL of the assembly containing a description of the old class which I want to deserialize.

I don't want to add a reference a this DLL in the project (I want be able to deserialize a class of any kind of assembly...)

How can I inform the Serializer/Deserializer to use my dynamically loaded assembly?

Comment: As long as the assembly is loaded (be it dynamically or by adding a reference to it) the serializer should find it. You said this "How can i inform the Serializer/Deserializer to use my dynamically loaded assembly?". That implies that the assembly is already "loaded" all you need to do is "inform the Serializer/Deserializer" about the "loading". That is a contradiction. The Serializer/Deserializer needs not be informed about anything. If you've loaded the assembly then it will use it. So load the assembly. You can't escape not loading it. To load an assembly dynamically use Assembly.LoadFrom

Comment: https://techdigger.wordpress.com/2007/12/22/deserializing-data-into-a-dynamically-loaded-assembly/ posting this in case someone else needs it.  The solution given here is to provide a custom SerializationBinder class with the BindToType method overridden to provide the deserialization Type.

Comment: You could use [AppDomain.AssemblyResolve](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.assemblyresolve.aspx) as shown in  [SerializationException for dynamically loaded Type](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9162553/3744182).  I think a custom `SerializationBinder` should work also, see [BinaryFormatter deserialize gives SerializationException](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2120055/3744182) and [How to create a SerializationBinder for the Binary Formatter that handles the moving of types from one assembly and namespace to another](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19927484/3744182).

Comment: Never used BinaryFormatter myself but can you go for another route instead of using BinaryFormatter like serializing yourself? E.g please see example here https://stackoverflow.com/a/1676053/2936309. The metadata mentioned here might be the same reason why you need the exact same dll while deserializing. Can you go around the issue by doing some of the work yourself?

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you are loading your assembly via [`Assembly.Load()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.assembly.load) or [`Assembly.LoadFrom()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.assembly.loadfrom), then as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9162553/3744182) to *[SerializationException for dynamically loaded Type](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9162279/3744182)* by [Chris Shain](https://stackoverflow.com/users/571563/chris-shain), you can use the [`AppDomain.AssemblyResolve`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.assemblyresolve.aspx) event to load your dynamic assembly during deserialization.  However, for security reasons you will want to prevent loading of entirely unexpected assemblies.

One possible implementation would be to introduce the following:

```
public class AssemblyResolver
{
    readonly string assemblyFullPath;
    readonly AssemblyName assemblyName;

    public AssemblyResolver(string assemblyName, string assemblyFullPath)
    {
        // You might want to validate here that assemblyPath really is an absolute not relative path.
        // See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5565029/check-if-full-path-given
        this.assemblyFullPath = assemblyFullPath;
        this.assemblyName = new AssemblyName(assemblyName);
    }

    public ResolveEventHandler AssemblyResolve
    {
        get
        {
            return (o, a) =>
                {
                    var name = new AssemblyName(a.Name);
                    if (name.Name == assemblyName.Name) // Check only the name if you want to ignore version.  Otherwise you can just check string equality.
                        return Assembly.LoadFrom(assemblyFullPath);
                    return null;
                };
        }
    }
}
```

Then, somewhere in startup, add an appropriate `ResolveEventHandler` to `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve` e.g. as follows:

```
class Program
{
    const string assemblyFullPath = @"C:\Full-path-to-my-assembly\MyAssembly.dll";
    const string assemblyName = @"MyAssembly, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null";

    static Program()
    {
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += new AssemblyResolver(assemblyName, assemblyFullPath).AssemblyResolve;
    }
```

This [`ResolveEventHandler`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.resolveeventhandler) checks to see whether the requested assembly has your dynamic assembly's name, and if so, loads the current version from the expected full path.

An alternative would be to write a custom [`SerializationBinder`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.serialization.serializationbinder) and attach it to [`BinaryFormatter.Binder`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.serialization.formatters.binary.binaryformatter.binder).  In [`BindToType (string assemblyName, string typeName)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.serialization.serializationbinder.bindtotype?view=netframework-4.8#System_Runtime_Serialization_SerializationBinder_BindToType_System_String_System_String_) the binder would need to check for types belonging to your dynamic assembly, and bind to them appropriately.  The trick here is dealing with situations in which your dynamically loaded types are nested in a generic from another assembly, e.g. a `List<MyClass>`.  In that case `assemblyName` will be the name of the assembly of `List<T>` not `MyClass`.  For details on how to do this see

- *[How to create a SerializationBinder for the Binary Formatter that handles the moving of types from one assembly and namespace to another](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19927484/3744182)*.
- *[BinaryFormatter deserialize gives SerializationException](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2120055/3744182)*

In [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18881659/binary-serialization-with-dynamically-loaded-net-assembly/59275509#comment104741487_18882174) [@sgnsajgon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/823040/sgnsajgon) asked, *I wonder why I cannot deserialize stream the same way I would do when signed assembly is explicitly referenced in project - just `formatter.Deserialize(stream)` and nothing else.*

While I don't know what Microsoft employees were thinking when they designed these classes (back in [.Net 1.1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.serialization.serializationbinder?view=netframework-1.1)), it might be because:

- In the words of Eric Lippert, [no one ever designed, specified, implemented, tested, documented and shipped that feature.](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/06/22/why-doesnt-c-implement-top-level-methods/)
- `BinaryFormatter` security is already somewhat of a [dumpster fire](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.serialization.formatters.binary.binaryformatter?view=net-5.0#remarks), but automatically calling [`Assembly.Load()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.assembly.load) on any unexpected assembly name in a `BinaryFormatter` stream might make things even worse.

  By "dumpster fire" I mean that, out-of-the-box, `BinaryFormatter` will instantiate and populate the types specified in the input stream *which might not be the types you are expecting*.  Thus you might do

  ```
   var instance = (MyClass)new BinaryFormatter().Deserialize(stream);
  ```

  But if the stream actually contains a serialized attack gadget such as [`TempFileCollection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.codedom.compiler.tempfilecollection?view=netframework-4.8) then the gadget will be created and populated and the attack will be effected.

  (For details on this sort of attack, see *[TypeNameHandling caution in Newtonsoft Json](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39565954)*, *[External json vulnerable because of Json.Net TypeNameHandling auto?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49038055)*,  *[How to configure Json.NET to create a vulnerable web API](https://www.alphabot.com/security/blog/2017/net/How-to-configure-Json.NET-to-create-a-vulnerable-web-API.html)* and Alvaro Muñoz & Oleksandr Mirosh's blackhat paper https://www.blackhat.com/docs/us-17/thursday/us-17-Munoz-Friday-The-13th-JSON-Attacks-wp.pdf.  Those links specify how to modify Json.NET's configuration to enable such attacks; `BinaryFormatter` is vulnerable to them in default configuration.)

  Now if `BinaryFormatter` were automatically calling `Assembly.Load()` on unrecognized assembly names, apps using it might additionally become vulnerable to a **[DLL planting attack](https://msrc-blog.microsoft.com/2018/04/04/triaging-a-dll-planting-vulnerability/)** where attack types from attack DLLs would get unexpectedly loaded from some unexpected location rather than a secure location, further exacerbating the attack risk.

  (Incidentally, if you do choose to write your own `SerializationBinder` you can filter out unexpected types and/or known attack types, thus reducing the risk of attack gadget injection.  This also can be harder than expected since `BinaryFormatter` streams often include serialized private or internal classes that you may not know to allow.)

As an aside, *[What are the deficiencies of the built-in BinaryFormatter based .Net serialization?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/703073/3744182)* gives a useful overview of other problems you might encounter using `BinaryFormatter`.

Answer (score 3):

Binary serialization has a no-nonsense attitude to DLL Hell.  It records the exact assembly that contained the type when the data was serialized.  And *insists* to find that exact assembly back when it deserializes the data.  Only way to be sure that serialized data matches the type, taking any shortcuts will merely ensure you'll get exceptions when your lucky, garbage data when you are not.  The odds that this will happen, sooner or later, are 100%.

So you'll need to completely scrap the idea that you can use a "dynamically loaded assembly" and get it to "deserialize a class of any kind", that's an illusion.  You can spin the wheel of fortune and put a `<bindingRedirect>` in the app.exe.config file to force the CLR to use a different assembly version.  Dealing with the mishaps are now your responsibility.  Many programmers grab the opportunity, few come back from the experience without learning a new lesson.  It has to be done to appreciate the consequences.  So go ahead.

Comment: I check if the assembly used to Serialize the instance is the same of the assembly loaded dynamically to Deserialize.
These assemblies seems the same: same name/version/culture/GUID. When i browse these Reflection.Assemly, differences found:
-locations
-filename (renamed dll)
-evidences
-# of class

These assemblies are not exacly the same (i was aware about that), but have the same ident and description of the serialized class :
-the number of class shouldn't be a problem because there is only one class marked [Serializable]
-this class have the same description of serializable fields.

Comment: From which criteria .Net consider theses assemblies are different ?

Comment: You said `And insists to find that exact assembly back when it deserializes the data`. I have exception even for signed assembly. Cannot deserialize in any way in case of dynamic assembly. No problem in case of referenced assembly.

Comment: Assembly loaded using Assembly.LoadFrom().

Comment: @sgnsajgon - You could use [AppDomain.AssemblyResolve](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.assemblyresolve.aspx) as shown in  [SerializationException for dynamically loaded Type](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9162553/3744182).  I think a custom `SerializationBinder` should work also, see [BinaryFormatter deserialize gives SerializationException](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2120055/3744182) and [How to create a SerializationBinder for the Binary Formatter that handles the moving of types from one assembly and namespace to another](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19927484).

Comment: @dbc Yes, there are workarounds, but I wonder why I cannot deserialize stream the same way I would do when signed assembly is explicitly referenced in project - just `formatter.Deserialize(stream)` and nothing else.

Comment: @sgnsajgon - *I wonder why I cannot deserialize stream the same way I would do when signed assembly is explicitly referenced in project*  1) Because, in the words of Erik Lippert, [no one ever designed, specified, implemented, tested, documented and shipped that feature.](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/06/22/why-doesnt-c-implement-top-level-methods/)  2) `BinaryFormatter` security is kind of a dumpster fire anyway, but loading any assembly by name even when not statically linked would make it *even worse* because unexpected types could get loaded by malicious payloads.

Comment: @sgnsajgon - you added a bounty here, but [SerializationException for dynamically loaded Type](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9162553/3744182) mostly looks like a legit duplicate.  What do you want to do?  Should I combine the comments above into an answer?

Comment: @dbc You right. The answer of Hans Passant does not clearly state that it is impossible to do it straightway, so I have asked. Then, I wonder why exception says `Unable to find assembly` rather that throwing `NotSupportedException` with proper problem description. Finally, security can be by-passed by `AppDomain.AssemblyResolve` which is very intrusive solution (affects entire AppDomain, not particular type scope). By-pass with `SerializationBinder` is IMO unclear and cumbersome. The last solution is to manually use `BinaryReader` and `BinaryWriter` but I would like to avoid it.

Comment: @dbc I think the solutions you have mentioned may work indeed, but they are not in any way more secure than solution with straightforward deserialization.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, some facts about binary serialization (skip them if you are interested only in the solutions):

- The goal of binary serialization is to make a 'bitwise' copy of an object. This often involves serialization of private fields, which may change from version to version. This is not a problem if deserialization happens always in the same process as the serialization (typical use cases: deep cloning, undo/redo, etc.).
- Therefore binary serialization is not recommended if the deserialization can occur in a different environment (including different platform, framework version, different versions of the assemblies or even the obfuscated version of the same assembly). If you know that any of these applies your case, then consider to use a text-based serialization by public members, such as XML or JSON serialization.
- It seems that Microsoft [started to abandon](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/38760) `BinaryFormatter`. Though it will be removed/marked as obsolete only in .NET 5 (will be able to be used as a package, though), there are many types also in .NET Core 2/3 that used to be serializable in the .NET Framework but are not serializable anymore in .NET Core (eg. `Type`, `Encoding`, `MemoryStream`, `ResourceSet`, delegates, etc.).

If you are still sure you want to solve the issue by using the `BinaryFormatter` you have the following options:

**1. Simplest case: only the assembly version has changed**

You can add a simple `assemblyBinding` to the app.config file. Just put the actual version in the `newVersion` attribute.

```xml
<runtime>
  <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="MyAssembly" publicKeyToken="null" culture="neutral" />
      <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
    </dependentAssembly>
  </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
```

**2. Assembly name and/or type name has also changed (or if you prefer programmatic solutions)**

`IFormatter` implementations (thus also `BinaryFormatter`) have a [`Binder`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.serialization.iformatter.binder) property. You can use it to control assembly/type name resolves:

```cs
internal class MyBinder : SerializationBinder
{
    public override Type BindToType(string assemblyName, string typeName)
    {
        // mapping the known old type to the new one
        if (assemblyName.StartsWith("MyAssembly, ") && typeName == "MyNamespace.MyOldType")
            return typeof(MyNewType);

        // for any other type returning null to apply the default resolving logic:
        return null;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```cs
var formatter = new BinaryFormatter { Binder = new MyBinder() };
return (MyNewType)formatter.Deserialize(myStream);
```

If you just need an assembly-version insensitive resolver you can use the [`WeakAssemblySerializationBinder`](http://docs.kgysoft.net/corelibraries/?topic=html/T_KGySoft_Serialization_Binary_WeakAssemblySerializationBinder.htm).

**3. The inner structure of the new type has also changed**

Since the OP did not cover this case I will not go too deep into the details. *TL;DR:* In this case you need to set the [`IFormatter.SurrogateSelector`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.serialization.iformatter.surrogateselector) property. You can use it along with the `Binder` property if both the type name and the inner layout has changed. In case you are interested there are some possible sub-cases cases at the **Remarks** section of the [`CustomSerializerSurrogateSelector`](https://docs.kgysoft.net/corelibraries/?topic=html/T_KGySoft_Serialization_Binary_CustomSerializerSurrogateSelector.htm) class.

---

**Final thoughts:**

- The error message in the question is a hint that using `BinaryFormatter` is maybe not the best choice for your goals. Use the solutions above only if you are sure you want to use binary serialization. Otherwise, you can try to use XML or JSON serialization instead, which serialize types basically by public members and do not store any assembly information.
- If you want to use the binders/surrogate selectors I linked above you can download the libraries from [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/KGySoft.CoreLibraries/). It actually contains also an alternative [binary serializer](https://kgysoft.net/corelibraries/#serialization) (disclaimer: written by me). Though it supports many simple types and collections natively (so no assembly identity is stored in the serialization stream) for custom types you may face the same issue as emerged in the question.