# External json vulnerable because of Json.Net TypeNameHandling auto?

Tags: c#, json.net

I'm operating a small website where users can upload custom "objects" defined in JSON. Recently I've learned about possible threats using JSON with automatic type deserialization: [JSON problem](https://www.alphabot.com/security/blog/2017/net/How-to-configure-Json.NET-to-create-a-vulnerable-web-API.html).  I think I understand the problematics but I have to ask to be sure. If I only deserialize the incoming JSON with a given specific type (here `MyObject`) `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyObject>(json, settings);` and no type inside `MyObject` and no subtype of any member of `MyObject` has the type `System.Object` or `dynamic` there is nothing that can go bad, right?

`TypeNameHandling` of `settings` is set to `TypeNameHandling.Auto` (let's not question this decision it probably could work with `None`, but I want to understand the question with it set to `Auto`.)

Edit:
More information: I have tested the JSON from the previously mentioned website:

```
{
    "obj": {
        "$type": "System.IO.FileInfo, System.IO.FileSystem",
        "fileName": "rce-test.txt",
        "IsReadOnly": true
    }
}
```

If `MyObject` has a `System.Object` or `dynamic` typed field `obj` I can reproduce the threat. But what I want to know: I'm on the safe side with bad prepared user-json even if MyObject is a very complex Object with lots of (derived) sub objects but NONE of them is or has a `System.Object` or a dynamic field (also not something like `List<Object>`)?  E.g. I could imagine that Json.NET does something like creating objects because of the `$type` information even if no according field in `MyObject` can be found.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] (i.e. show us your code).

Comment: In the blogpost it has an example of a malicious payload. Did you test using that malicious payload?

Comment: thanks, I've added more information

Comment: `But what I want to know: I'm on the safe side with bad prepared user-json even if MyObject is a very complex Object with lots of (derived) sub objects but NONE of them is or has a System.Object or a dynamic field (also not something like List<Object>)?` What happened when you tried it?

Comment: I was not able to replicate it without Object or dynamic fields. But I'm not sure if I thought of all possible attack vectors.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeNameHandling caution in Newtonsoft Json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39565954/typenamehandling-caution-in-newtonsoft-json)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

**TL/DR**:  In the absence of any obvious `object` or `dynamic` members, you *may well* be safe, but you are not *guaranteed* to be safe.  To further decrease your risk you should follow the recommendations from the [Newtonsoft documentation](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_TypeNameHandling.htm):

> [TypeNameHandling](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonSerializer_TypeNameHandling.htm) should be used with caution when your application deserializes JSON from an external source. Incoming types should be validated with a custom [SerializationBinder](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonSerializer_SerializationBinder.htm) when deserializing with a value other than None.

**Full Answer**

The attacks described in *[How to configure Json.NET to create a vulnerable web API](https://www.alphabot.com/security/blog/2017/net/How-to-configure-Json.NET-to-create-a-vulnerable-web-API.html)*, *[TypeNameHandling caution in Newtonsoft Json](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39565954/3744182)* and Alvaro Muñoz & Oleksandr Mirosh's [blackhat paper](https://www.blackhat.com/docs/us-17/thursday/us-17-Munoz-Friday-The-13th-JSON-Attacks-wp.pdf) all depend on using the [`TypeNameHandling` setting](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializeTypeNameHandling.htm) of Json.NET to trick the receiver into constructing an **attack gadget** - a instance of a type that when constructed, populated or disposed effects an attack on the receiving system.

Json.NET does two things that help protect against such attacks.  Firstly, it ignores unknown properties.  Thus simply adding an additional, unknown property to a JSON payload whose value contains a `"$type"` property should do no harm.  Secondly, during deserialization of a polymorphic value, when resolving the `"$type"` property, it checks to see whether the resolved type is compatible with the expected type in [`JsonSerializerInternalReader.ResolveTypeName()`](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Serialization/JsonSerializerInternalReader.cs#L770):

> ```
>     if (objectType != null
> #if HAVE_DYNAMIC
>         && objectType != typeof(IDynamicMetaObjectProvider)
> #endif
>         && !objectType.IsAssignableFrom(specifiedType))
>     {
>         throw JsonSerializationException.Create(reader, "Type specified in JSON '{0}' is not compatible with '{1}'.".FormatWith(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, specifiedType.AssemblyQualifiedName, objectType.AssemblyQualifiedName));
>     }
> ```

If the expected type of the polymorphic value is not compatible with any attack gadget type, the attack will fail.  Provided you have no serializable members of type `object`, `dynamic` or `IDynamicMetaObjectProvider`, this is likely to be true.  But not certain!

Cases in which an attack gadget might get constructed even without any obvious untyped members in your data model include:

- Deserialization of untyped *collections*.  If you are deserializing any sort of untyped collection or dictionary such as `ArrayList`, `List<object>`, `Dictionary<string, dynamic>` or [`HashTable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.hashtable.aspx), then your system is vulnerable to attack gadgets contained in the collection's items.
- Deserialization of any of the dozens of collections inheriting from [`CollectionBase`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.collectionbase(v=vs.110).aspx).  This type predates the introduction of generics in .Net and represents a "semi-typed" collection, in which the types of the items are validated in runtime as they are added.  Since the validation occurs after construction, there is a window in which an attack gadget might get constructed.

  Sample [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/LR120U) showing just this.
- Deserialization of values that share a common base type or interface with an attack gadget other than just `object`.  [`TempFileCollection`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/compmod/system/codedom/compiler/TempFiles.cs) implements `ICollection` and `IDisposable`.  [`ObjectDataProvider`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.objectdataprovider.aspx) implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` and `ISupportInitialize`.  If you have any polymorphic members or values that are declared to be any of these interfaces, you are vulnerable.
- Deserialization of types that implement [`ISerializable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.iserializable.aspx).  Json.NET [supports this interface](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializationGuide.htm#ISerializable) by default, and it is possible that a seemingly-harmless type in some external library is deserializing untyped members inside its streaming constructor without your knowledge.

  One obvious example is `Sytem.Exception` (or any of its subtypes) which deserializes an untyped dictionary `"Data"` inside its [streaming constructor](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/exception.cs,90) which corresponds to the untyped dictionary [`Exception.Data`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.exception.data(v=vs.110).aspx).  If you are deserializing an `Exception` (contained in a log file for example, which is very common), the following JSON should effect an attack:

  ```
  {
    "$type": "System.Exception, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089",
    "ClassName": "System.Exception",
    "Message": "naughty exception",
    "Data": {
      "$type": "System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089",
      "data": {
        "$type": "System.IO.FileInfo, System.IO.FileSystem",
        "fileName": "rce-test.txt",
        "IsReadOnly": true    
      }
    },
  }
  ```

  The attack can be mitigated without creation of a custom serialization binder by setting [`DefaultContractResolver.IgnoreSerializableInterface = true`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_DefaultContractResolver_IgnoreSerializableInterface.htm).  Of course, this may cause problems with serialization of certain .Net class library types.
- Deserializing types marked with [`[Serializable]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serializableattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) can have a similar problem if you set [`DefaultContractResolver.IgnoreSerializableAttribute = false`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_DefaultContractResolver_IgnoreSerializableAttribute.htm).  However, the default is `true`, so you should be OK if you don't change this setting.
- Deserializing types with members that you *think* are not serialized -- but will be deserialized if present.  E.g. consider the following type:

  ```
  public MyType
  {
      public object tempData;
      public bool ShouldSerializeTempData() { return false; }
  }
  ```

  Thanks to Json.NET's [conditional serialization](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ConditionalProperties.htm) functionality, the `tempData` member will never be serialized, so you might think you're in the clear.  But it will be *deserialized* if present!  An attacker who decompiles your code and notices such a member will be able to craft an attack gadget payload for `MyType`.

And that's just what I was able to think of off the top of my head.  As you can see, verifying that, in a large object graph, there is never an attempt to deserialize a polymorphic type that is compatible with some attack gadget is substantially nontrivial.  Thus I'd strongly recommend the additional protection of a custom [`SerializationBinder`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonSerializer_SerializationBinder.htm) that ensures that no unexpected types are deserialized.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer!
So the solution is to use a SerializationBinder and "Whitelist" all possible allowed types.