# JsonConvert serialize/deserialize jagged array with TypeNameHandling enabled

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net

I am trying to deserialize an object with a jagged and multidimensional array property:

```
public abstract class Foo {}

public class Baz
{
    public readonly List<Foo> Foos;

    public Baz()
    {
        Foos = new List<Foo>();
    }
}

public class Bar : Foo
{
    public readonly double[][,,] Values;

    public Bar(double[][,,] values)
    {
        Values = values;
    }
}
```

Since `Baz` has a `List<Foo>` and `Foo` is an abstract class, I want to preserve types of Foo's in the serialized string, so I have to use `TypeNameHandling.All`:

```
JsonSerializerSettings settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All,
    Formatting = Formatting.Indented
};
```

However, when I run the following code:

```
var barValues = new double[][,,] { new double[,,] {{{ 1 }}} };

var baz = new Baz();
baz.Foos.Add(new Bar(barValues));

var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(baz, settings);
var baz2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Baz>(json, settings);
```

I got an exception:

> Type specified in JSON 'System.Double[,][], System.Private.CoreLib,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e' is
>   not compatible with 'System.Double[,,][], System.Private.CoreLib,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e'.
>   Path 'Foos.$values[0].Values.$type', line 9, position 63.'

And if I inspect the serialized string, it looks rather strange:

```
"Values": {
   "$type": "System.Double[,][], System.Private.CoreLib",
   ...
}
```

Why `JsonConvert` can not deserialize the string in that case ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This appears to be a bug with `TypeNameHandling.Arrays` and multidimensional arrays of rank > 2.**

I can reproduce the problem more easily by serializing a 3d double array using `TypeNameHandling.Arrays`:

```
var root = new double[,,] { { { 1 } } };

var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings { TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Arrays };
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(root, Formatting.Indented, settings);

// Try to deserialize to the same type as root
// but get an exception instead:
var root2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType(json, root, settings);
```

The JSON generated by the code above is:

```
{
  "$type": "System.Double[,], mscorlib",
  "$values": [ [ [ 1.0 ] ] ]
}
```

The presence of the `"$type"` property is to be expected, and is documented in *[TypeNameHandling setting](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializeTypeNameHandling.htm)*, but as you note it looks wrong: it should have an extra dimension in the array type like so:

```
  "$type": "System.Double[,,], mscorlib",
```

And in fact I can deserialize the JSON successfully if I manually replace the `[,]` with `[,,]` like so:

```
// No exception!
JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType(json.Replace("[,]", "[,,]"), root, settings)
```

Finally, if I try the same test with a 2d array instead of a 3d array, the test passes.  Demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/fQPWXr).

**The cause** appears to be a bug in the routine [`ReflectionUtils.RemoveAssemblyDetails`](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/44539a8f002bc4d6dae919a0340531661c9bdd5d/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Utilities/ReflectionUtils.cs#L179) when called at the following traceback:

```
Newtonsoft.Json.Utilities.ReflectionUtils.RemoveAssemblyDetails(string) C#
Newtonsoft.Json.Utilities.ReflectionUtils.GetTypeName(System.Type, Newtonsoft.Json.TypeNameAssemblyFormatHandling, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.ISerializationBinder)  C#
Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.WriteTypeProperty(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonWriter, System.Type)   C#
Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.WriteStartArray(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonWriter, object, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonArrayContract, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonProperty, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonContainerContract, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonProperty)    C#
```

When called, the input parameter has the value

```
System.Double[,,], mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
```

But the returned value is

```
System.Double[,], mscorlib
```

which is clearly wrong.

An issue could be reported to Newtonsoft [here](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues) if desired.

**Update:** a similar issue was opened today: *[Type of multi-dimensional array is incorrect #1918](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues/1918)*.

**As a workaround**, you should limit the scope of properties for which you output type information to situations where a given JSON object might, in practice, be polymorphic.  Possibilities include:

1. You could serialize your object graph with `TypeNameHandling.None` but mark your polymorphic collections with [`JsonPropertyAttribute.ItemTypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonPropertyAttribute_ItemTypeNameHandling.htm) like so:

   ```
   public class Baz
   {
       [JsonProperty(ItemTypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto)]
       public readonly List<Foo> Foos;

       public Baz()
       {
           Foos = new List<Foo>();
       }
   }
   ```

   This solution results in less bloated JSON and also minimizes the security risks of using `TypeNameHandling` that are described in *[TypeNameHandling caution in Newtonsoft Json](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39565954/3744182)* and *[External json vulnerable because of Json.Net TypeNameHandling auto?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49038055/3744182)* and thus is the preferable solution.
2. You could serialize your object graph with `TypeNameHandling.None` and use a [custom contract resolver](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/contractresolver.htm#CustomIContractResolverExamples) to set [`JsonArrayContract.ItemTypeNameHandling`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_JsonContainerContract_ItemTypeNameHandling.htm) to `TypeNameHandling.Auto` for collections with potentially polymorphic items, by overriding [`DefaultContractResolver.CreateArrayContract`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_DefaultContractResolver_CreateArrayContract.htm).

   This would be the solution to use if you cannot add Json.NET attributes to your types.
3. You could serialize your object graph with `TypeNameHandling.Auto` or `TypeNameHandling.Objects`.

   Either option will avoid the bug and also reduce bloat in your JSON, but will not reduce your security risks.
4. You could serialize your object graph with [`JsonSerializerSettings.TypeNameAssemblyFormatHandling = TypeNameAssemblyFormatHandling.Full`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_TypeNameAssemblyFormatHandling.htm).

   This avoids the call to `RemoveAssemblyDetails()` but results in even more bloated JSON and does not avoid the possible security risks.