# Issue with WCF type serialization

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, null, datacontractserializer

I'm facing a strange issue with WCF serialization. My project has a type named `RefEntity` which has a property of another type named `RefDomain`. A WCF service defines two methods, one takes type `RefEntity` as parameter, and another takes type `RefDomain` as parameter.

The method with the `RefDomain` parameter doesn't seem to serialize the object as all the properties have `null` value on the service side. Whereas, the method with `RefEntity` parameter (and `RefDomain` as a member) works as expected (`RefDomain` member is serialized as expected).

What am I missing here?

```
public class RefDomain
{
    private string name;
    private RefDomain parent;
    private Type entityType;

    public string Name
    {
        get => this.name;
        protected set => this.name = value;
    }

    public RefDomain Parent
    {
          get => this.parent;
          protected set => this.parent = value;
    }

    public Type RefEntityType
    {
          get => this.entityType;
          protected set => this.entityType = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your properties are all `protected`, how are they ever set to begin with?

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to show how an instance of `RefDomain` is constructed and serialized?

Comment: And if `RefDomain` can be serialized when referred to by `RefEntity`, can you share a [mcve] showing that as well?

Comment: Is it only `RefEntityType` that is not serialized? Is it useful to change the parameter type?

Comment: @Jiayao - As described in the question, my service has a method which takes `RefDomain` type as parameter, and nothing is serialized. But another method which takes `RefEntity` as parameter, and has `RefDomain` type as one of its members, everything is serialized as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Your properties have protected setters, and `DataContractSerializer` will only serialize properties that are fully public, unless marked with [data contract attributes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/using-data-contracts).

Once you apply the necessary `[DataContract]` and `[DataMember]` attributes, you will discover a second problem, namely that `DataContractSerializer` cannot serialize values of type `System.Type`.  (Demo fiddle #1 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/mNeEpS)).  To serialize your `Type RefEntityType` property, you will need to use some sort of surrogate for `Type` that can be serialized, for instance a string.

Thus the following version of `RefDomain` can be serialized via the data contract serializer:

```
public class RefDomain
{
    private string name;
    private RefDomain parent;
    private Type entityType;

    [DataMember]
    public string Name
    {
        get => this.name;
        protected set => this.name = value;
    }

    [DataMember]
    public RefDomain Parent
    {
          get => this.parent;
          protected set => this.parent = value;
    }

    public Type RefEntityType
    {
          get => this.entityType;
          protected set => this.entityType = value;
    }

    [DataMember(Name = "RefEntityType")]
    string RefEntityTypeString 
    {
        get
        {
            return RefEntityType?.FullName;
        }
        set
        {
            // Note that simply deserializing a type supplied over the wire will make your application vulnerable to type injection attacks,
            // in which an attacker tricks you into constructing a type that effects an attack when constructed, deserialized or disposed.  
            // This is a known vulnerability with Json.NET's TypeNameHandling.None.  See for details
            // https://www.blackhat.com/docs/us-17/thursday/us-17-Munoz-Friday-The-13th-JSON-Attacks-wp.pdf
            // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39565954/typenamehandling-caution-in-newtonsoft-json/
            // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49038055/external-json-vulnerable-because-of-json-net-typenamehandling-auto
            var type = value == null ? null : Type.GetType(value);
            // Check the type against a whitelist here?
            RefEntityType = type;
        }
    }
    
    // Your class was had no way to set the protected properties, so I added a parameterized constructor.
    public RefDomain() { }
    public RefDomain(string name, RefDomain parent, Type entityType) => (this.name, this.parent, this.entityType) = (name, parent, entityType);
}
```

Notes:

1. Deserializing a type supplied over the wire will make your application vulnerable to **attack gadget deserialization attacks**, in which an attacker tricks your app into constructing a type that effects an attack when constructed, deserialized or disposed.  This is a known vulnerability with Json.NET's [`TypeNameHandling`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_TypeNameHandling.htm).  See for details:

   - https://www.blackhat.com/docs/us-17/thursday/us-17-Munoz-Friday-The-13th-JSON-Attacks-wp.pdf
   - [TypeNameHandling caution in Newtonsoft Json](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39565954/3744182)
   - [External json vulnerable because of Json.Net TypeNameHandling auto?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49038055/3744182)

   If your app ever constructs an instance of your `RefEntityType`, you app may become vulnerable to such attacks.  To prevent this, you could check the deserialized type against a whitelist of allowed types.
2. In your question, you ask why the partially public properties of `RefDomain` are serialized **when it is serialized as a member of some other root object `RefEntity`**.  There is not enough information in your question to explain why this is happening.  Perhaps the endpoint where the `RefEntity` is serialized is using a has subclassed `RefDomain`, or uses a [serialization surrogate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/extending/data-contract-surrogates), or has set [`DataContractSerializerSettings.SerializeReadOnlyTypes = true`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractserializersettings.serializereadonlytypes).

   But regardless of why partially public properties `RefDomain` properties are serialized when inside `RefEntity`, if you want those properties serialized in all contexts, it is correct and sufficient to mark `RefDomain` with `[DataContract]` and the properties with `[DataMember]`

Demo fiddle #2 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/1W9ePn).

Comment: If protected setters is the issue, then how come the same type is serialized with `RefEntity` type? Allow me some time and I will share the complete code

Comment: @SanthoshShanmugam - here is a demo of serializing your `RefDomain` without data contract attributes: https://dotnetfiddle.net/1JKjI6.  As you can see, nothing is serialized.

Comment: You're right @dbc! When I modified the `RefDomain` class with public setters, WCF is able to serialize the type, and now the issue is with the System.Type member. But I fail to understand is how is this working with the `RefEntity` type. Let me share a working example.

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce the issue with [.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/K4s5zS) (not sure why). But you can look at the code that is in my codebase. Is there a way we can connect offline and I will demo the issue to you?

Comment: Any chance you're using [dynamic proxies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/fundamentals/proxies)?

Comment: Nope, not using dynamic proxies

Comment: @SanthoshShanmugam - absent a [mcve] it's going to be hard for us to guess why serializing of `RefDomain` works when a member of `RefEntity`.  Maybe the `RefEntity` method uses a [serialization surrogate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/extending/data-contract-surrogates).  Maybe the `RefEntity` method sets [`DataContractSerializerSettings.SerializeReadOnlyTypes`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractserializersettings.serializereadonlytypes) somewhere.

Comment: @SanthoshShanmugam - but regardless of why get-only properties `RefDomain ` properties are serialized when inside `RefEntity`, if you want those properties serialized in all contexts, it is sufficient to mark them with `[DataMember`].

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, user-defined types used in wcf need to be tagged with the Data Contract attribute, and members need to be tagged with the Data Member attribute.

You can either mark RefDomain as a Data Contract attribute or create a separate class to hold data from RefDomain and pass it through wcf.